# Get CGRect of a NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have tried many solutions provided in stackoverflow but I can't get the correct rect of a NSAttributedString.
As an instance the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621084/boundingrectwithsize-for-nsattributedstring-returning-wrong-size) does not work :

```
CGRect paragraphRect =
  [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(300.f, CGFLOAT_MAX)
  options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
  context:nil];
```

Below my code :

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrapStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragrapStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
paragrapStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.2;

NSMutableAttributedString *textMutableAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textString];
[textMutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragrapStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [textMutableAttributedString.string length])];
[textMutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:114/255. green:132/255. blue:141/255. alpha:1] range:NSMakeRange(0,[textMutableAttributedString.string length])];
[textMutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragrapStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [textMutableAttributedString.string length])];

NSAttributedString *textAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:textMutableAttributedString];

[text setAttributedText:textAttributedString];

CGRect textAttributedStringRect = [textAttributedString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(text.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                                                     options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                                     context:nil];
```

textAttributedStringRect computed value is origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=260.12695, height=33.120003) while text.frame.size.width original value is 260. The computed height is completely wrong...

I have read many answers on this specific problem and none of them solve it. I hope I will have someone who knows an accurate way to calculate the rect.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `floorf(textAttributedStringRect.size.width)`?

Comment: To be sure I have replay the test with floorf. It's not a problem of CGFloat precision but rather that 33 is not even close of the correct height

Comment: What is the height you expect to see?

Comment: When I use the computed height to resize the UILabel the string is truncated. Height should be at least 20px taller

Comment: Removing NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading did the trick for me.

Comment: Using `UILabel`'s `sizeToFit` method would be sufficient to resize your `UILabel`.

Comment: @Dimillian77 I tried to remove NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading but textAttributedString give the exact same result

Comment: @duci9y For UILabel it's ok but when I need to draw the NSAttributedString I need the correct rect

Comment: Why would you need to draw the string? Won't a label work?

Comment: I need to draw the NSAttributedString when I build UITableViewCell via drawRect

Comment: You are over-complicating things. What you need to do can be simply done by using a UILabel.

Comment: On complex view hierarchies drawing is still the fastest way to build them. Unless there is new benchmarks available that you know?

Comment: Um… using a UILabel would simply mean you will not have to draw things on your own. UILabel would draw the text for you. And I'm not sure about your first statement.

Comment: @duci9y When there is several subviews in a mother UIView there is timing penalty to draw them. To get the view hierarchy renders faster is common to draw the different elements and not use directly views

Comment: You're wrong. The latency is absurdly minuscule to be noticeable. Unless you're using super-expensive drawing code in custom views.

Comment: The problem was elsewhere. The solution [here][1] works


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621084/boundingrectwithsize-for-nsattributedstring-returning-wrong-size