# NSString boundingRectWithSize returning unnecessarily tall height

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstring

When using `[NSString boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes]` the size of the rect that is returned is taller than I would expect for certain strings. The height returned appears to represent the maximum possible height of a string with the given attributes, rather than the height of the string itself.

Assuming the same attributes and options, the height returned for the string "`cars`" is the same height returned for the string "`ÉTAS-UNIS`" (note the accent on the E).

I would have expected `boundingRectWithSize` to only consider the characters in the given string, which in my opinion would have it return a shorter height for the string "`cars`".

In the attached screenshots, I've filled the rect returned from `boundingRectWithSize` and outlined in red what I would have assumed the bounding rect should have been. The width of the rect is pretty much as I would expect but the height is considerably taller than I would have expected. Why is that?

[image: Bounding Rect Example]

Sample code:

```
NSRect boundingRect = NSZeroRect;
NSSize constraintSize = NSMakeSize(CGFLOAT_MAX, 0);

NSString *lowercaseString = @"cars";
NSString *uppercaseString = @"ÉTAS-UNIS";
NSString *capitalizedString = @"Japan";

NSFont *drawingFont = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:24.0];
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : drawingFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [NSColor blackColor]};

boundingRect = [lowercaseString boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize options:0 attributes:attributes];
NSLog(@"Lowercase rect: %@", NSStringFromRect(boundingRect));

boundingRect = [uppercaseString boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize options:0 attributes:attributes];
NSLog(@"Uppercase rect: %@", NSStringFromRect(boundingRect));

boundingRect = [capitalizedString boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize options:0 attributes:attributes];
NSLog(@"Capitalized rect: %@", NSStringFromRect(boundingRect));
```

Output:

```
Lowercase rect: {{0, -6}, {43.1953125, 33}}
Uppercase rect: {{0, -6}, {128.44921875, 33}}
Capitalized rect: {{0, -6}, {64.5, 33}}
```

Comment: Please check the answer for the similar question here- [http://stackoverflow.com/a/27289303/591811][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27289303/591811

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You might want to use `NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics` in the options. From the [docs](http://nathanmock.com/files/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS6.0.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics):

> `NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics`
>
> Use the image glyph bounds (instead of the typographic bounds) when computing layout.

Comment: I was all but certain I'd tried that flag but I guess I'd always tried it alongside the `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin` flag, which didn't produce the results I wanted. Used alone, it does. Thank you. It seems remarkably difficult to draw a perfectly sized rect behind some truncated text. Asking for the bounding rect with `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin` includes "padding", but that flag appears needed for `NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine` to be used.

Answer (score 5):

@omz still gets credit for making this work for me. His answer made me look around CoreText some more since I assume something like `boundingRectWithSize` ultimately calls a CoreText function.

In Session 226 from WWDC 2012 there was an entire section devoted to calculating the metrics of a line and, to my surprise, they talked about a new CoreText function called `CTLineGetBoundsWithOptions`.

As far as I can tell, that method is only documented in `CTLine.h` and in the `CoreText Changes` document. It certainly doesn't come up (for me) when doing a normal search in the documentation.

But it appears to work and in my testing it returns the exact same result as `boundingRectWithSize` for all the fonts installed on my system. Even better, is that it appears to be almost 2x faster than `boundingRectWithSize`.

As the WWDC video mentions, it's a bit obscure why you'd need to calculate the bounds of a string without taking things like line height into account, but if you do need to do that, then I think this might be the best method to use. As always, YMMV.

Rough sample code:

```
NSFont *font = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
NSDictionary *attributes = @{(__bridge NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName : font};
NSAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text attributes:attributes];

CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)attributeString);
CGRect bounds = CTLineGetBoundsWithOptions(line, kCTLineBoundsUseGlyphPathBounds);

CFRelease(line);

return NSRectFromCGRect(bounds);
```

Comment: `CTLineGetBoundsWithOptions` is also mentioned in the "what's new" document for OS 10.8.

Comment: Thank you for the mention of CTLineGetBoundsWithOptions returns the correct text size while boundingRectWithSize: options: context: gives me double the height in iOS 8.  Totally weird. Now it's time to figure out how to have the text wrap.

Comment: I'm seeing iOS8 double the height of calculated text, too, regardless of the options I set.  CTLineGetBoundsWithOptions works like a charm.

Comment: this is giving for width. Not Height.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the `boundingRectWithSize` function, but it didn't work for me.

What did work was `sizeThatFits`

Usage:

```
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(myLabel.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)

CGSize size = [myLabel sizeThatFits:maxSize];
```

Comment: The question is tagged as both iOS and OSX, but I think `sizeThatFits:` is only available on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3+ solution based on [omz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21273065/3151675):

```
let string: NSString = "test"
let maxSize = NSSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
let boundingRect = string.boundingRect(with: maxSize, options: .usesDeviceMetrics, attributes: <string attributes>)
```