# Calculate intrinsicContentSize of UILabel, with exact precision

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uilabel, textkit

How can I use `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` to return **exactly** the same size than `intrinsicContentSize` of a `UILabel`?

For example, if I use it like below, I get differences of up to 1 pixel:

```
const CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
NSDictionary * attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:self.font};
CGSize textSize = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:maxSize
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                                        attributes:attributes
                                           context:nil].size;
NSLog(@"1: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(label.intrinsicContentSize));
NSLog(@"2: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(textSize));
```

E.g:

```
1: {53, 17}
2: {52.122002, 18}
```

The documentation of `boundingRectWithSize` says:

> In iOS 7 and later, this method returns fractional sizes (in the size
>   component of the returned CGRect); to use a returned size to size
>   views, you must use raise its value to the nearest higher integer
>   using the ceil function.

So the difference between `53` and `52.122002` makes sense and can be dealt with by using `ceil`. However, the 1-pixel height difference can't.

Should I be using something else entirely?

Comment: What does the result of `CGRectIntegral` give you?

Comment: {53,18}. The problem is the difference of 1 pixel.

Comment: Would this answer help you at all?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21273065/1671729