# Remove Top And Bottom Padding From A UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` but it has extra padding on the top and bottom for some reason. I'd like the height of the label to be exactly the height of the text inside it.

I've been searching around on other questions and can't seem to find a solution that actually works. Or the solution requires you to call something in your `layoutSubviews` method of your VC, but I want all my view code to be stored in my view file.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: You'll probably find, that as far as the system is concerned, the label's height does match that of the text, based on the way font and text is rendered.  Maybe see [About Text Handling in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) for a better visual guide

Comment: @MadProgrammer But "T" would be the highest character. Why is there still the extra space above it, and the tiny space below the "y"?

Comment: Not necessarily, look at the link. The “height” may not be calculated on the the text, but based on the overall font metrics

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it but from reading through the link I only see the graphical representation of the font, I don't see a single mention of how the height is rendered.

Comment: That why I said “probably”, based on my experience with other apis/languages, the height isn’t always calculated off the text, but off the font metrics, but I’m not fully aware of how it works in iOS

Comment: I did some quick testing with a `UILabel` and it's `intrinsicContentSize` and `String#boundingRect` and could determine both values are returning the same bounding box, which suggests that `UILabel` is using the calculation and that it produces the padding above and below the text.  I'm not sure if there is a "easy" way to remove this

Comment: Further, when I look at `UIFont#lineHeight`, it returns the same value `intrinsicContentSize` and `String#boundingRect`, regardless of text I use, which suggests that the API isn't looking at the text, but the font metrics

Comment: Hmm, thats not looking good for me lol. I have no clue why something so simple can't be easily changed

Comment: That's because rendering text/font isn't simple, it's rather complicated and should follow typographical rules in order to make sure its consistent. You could look at some of the properties of `UIFont` to see if there is anything which might help you "adjust" the frame, but I think you'll find it inconsistent

Comment: I did something like this once, I'm not sure you want to go down this rabbit whole but there is a way you can figure this out if you know the height / width of the chars in the font you're using and then work from there

Comment: @AntersBear, The only reason this is an issue for me is because in my design programs, the height of the labels is exactly the height of the tallest character within them. So when I go to make the views in code, it doesn't quite look how I had planned.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21273065/3151675

Answer (score 1):

Call like;

```
let labelSize = UILabelWidthBasedOnTextLength(with: titleLabel)
```

Then use like labelSize.width, to apply constraints.

```
func UILabelWidthBasedOnTextLength(with label: UILabel) -> CGSize? {
        guard let text = label.text,
              let font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName,
                                size: label.font.pointSize) else { return nil }

    var frame: CGRect = label.frame
    frame.size = text.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font])
    return frame.size
}
```

This question asked very long ago, but I just wanted to contribute this approach. Maybe this will be usefull for any new developers.