# Contenting deprecated sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize to boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:

Tags: ios, objective-c, deprecation-warning

How can I convert

```
 CGSize labelHeighSize = [text sizeWithFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16] constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
```

to

```
CGSize labelHeighSize = [text boundingRectWithSize:maximumSize options:  attributes:  context:
```

Comment: You can reference to, I used it, it seems to be OK
[boundingRectWithSize]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621084/boundingrectwithsize-for-nsattributedstring-returning-wrong-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the method:

```
 - (CGRect)   boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size 
                           options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options 
                        attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes 
                           context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context;
```

returns `CGRect` not the `CGSize` so you need to use `CGRect`.

**EDIT**
according to apple docs see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin), it says

> This option is ignored if `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin` is not
>   also set. In addition, the line break mode must be either
>   `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` or `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping` for this option
>   to take effect. The line break mode can be specified in a paragraph
>   style passed in the attributes dictionary argument of the drawing
>   methods.

Below is the sample code that you can use:

```
NSString *text = @"Some text to measure";
UIFont *labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init];
//set the line break mode
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping; 

NSDictionary *attrDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:labelFont,
                                       NSFontAttributeName,
                                       paragraphStyle,
                                       NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                       nil];


//assume your maximumSize contains {255, MAXFLOAT}     
CGRect lblRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){225, MAXFLOAT} 
                                    options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                 attributes:attrDict 
                                    context:nil];
CGSize labelHeighSize = lblRect.size;
```

Comment: How can I add lineBreakMode ?

Comment: `CGSize labelHeighSize = lblRect.size;` <- Does it work?