# uilabel sizetofit doesn't work uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that has two `UILabels` that sit next to each other. I need the `UILabel` on the left to grow as it's text grows and the `UILabel` on the right of it it to move over to the right as this happens.

I am using Autolayout and have setup the constraints. However the UILabel on the left never fits the text it has. I have tried `sizeToFit` however this does;t do anything. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

I thought auto layout will grow the UILabels based on their intrinsic content sizes?

**Edit**

Here is what my cell looks like:

[image]

So the top left label has the following constraints:

Pinned to left / top edges. 
Width constraint 
Horizontal spacing to label to its right.

The label to its right has similar constraints too.

I need the UIImageView and the grey label to move to the right as the label on the far left grows.

Comment: sizeToFit wont work if Autolayout is enabled. Yo need to set your constraints instead

Comment: I've tried it without auto layout and it still doesn't work. I will upload a picture now of the auto layout constraints.

Comment: If not mistaking `sizeToFit` will only decrease the width of your `UILabel`. You have to define size that is greater than the text length, or increase the number of lines. Set the text and call `sizeToFit`. You should do this every time you want to update your text as `sizeToFit` will never expand the `UILabel's` width

Comment: All I need is the label to fit the text it contains. That is not happening. I assume once that works, the UILabel and UIImageView to its right will move as the constraints will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sizeToFit` will only adjust itself within its given size. If the size of label is *(100, 30)* and if the text size comes to *(30, 30)* then it will change its size to *(30, 30)*.

Now, if the size of label is *(30, 30)* and text size comes to *(50, 30)* then it will stick to the size allocated for it. In short it takes the minimum out of the *text size* and allocated size. i.e `MIN(actualSize, textSize)`.

For getting the actual width required, you should use (NSString UIKit Additions):

```
 - (CGRect)   boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size 
                           options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options 
                        attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes 
                           context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context;
```

And sorry to say but you need to do this every time you assign text to the label.

Example can be find in [this @Shan's SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23076125/923340) answer.