# UITextView sizeThatFits returns different size than boundingRectWithSize

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

Need the required height of `UITextView`. `sizeThatFits` returns bigger, but the correct height than `boundingRectWithSize`. Why difference exist?

At two places I need to know the height. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

I do not think it is efficient to create always a `UITextView` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` just to know what height is required.

What workaround do you know to calculate height of a `UITextView` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 3):

I met similar problem last month for UITableView, and I use boundingRectWithSize to calculate the size, it is actually correct. I then put it into UITextView.

Some mistakes I made:

1. I forget to set the same font size when calculating and for UITextView
2. UITextView has margins, I will manually add it in heightForRowAtIndexPath and set textContainerInset to the same one.

Hope it helps you.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
    NSUInteger axisIndex = section - 2;
    yAxis *yAxisObj = self.yAxisInfoArray[axisIndex];
    boundingRect = [yAxisObj.yAxisDescription boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.descriptionViewWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                                                        attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.contentFont}
                                                           context:nil];


    return boundingRect.size.height + TEXT_TOP_MARGIN + TEXT_BOTTOM_MARGIN;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellId = @"ChartDescriptionCell";
    ChartDescriptionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[ChartDescriptionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
        cell.textView.bounces = NO;
        cell.textView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        cell.textView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        cell.textView.font = self.contentFont;
        cell.textView.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHex:@"#333333"];
        cell.textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(TEXT_TOP_MARGIN, -5, TEXT_BOTTOM_MARGIN, -5);
    }
    NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
    NSUInteger axisIndex = section - 2;
    yAxis *yAxisObj = self.yAxisInfoArray[axisIndex];
    cell.textView.text = yAxisObj.yAxisDescription;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, key was:

    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

Answer (score 0):

`boundingRectWithSize` returns size for text, so you should manually provide your font.

`sizeThatFits` returns size of UITextView with this text inside

If you are pointing to iOS 8 and above you can use Dynamic cell height which is very easy. In case of iOS 7 you need some workaround.

Tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Related question with nice answer: [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Comment: do you have any idea how to update `textView` height when content changes? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32497229/how-update-height-of-the-cell-with-uitableviewautomaticdimension

Comment: @János try to use `textViewDidChange` delegate method and calculate new height each time.

Comment: @János I didn't understand you. You should to use constraints if you want dynamic UITableViewCell height. You can set for example 100 for UITextView and if text is bigger than 100 you need to update height constraint of UITextView

Comment: need constraints, but not height constraint, check image in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights/18746930#18746930