# How to update height of the cell with UITableViewAutomaticDimension?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` in a tableViewCell, and using the iOS 8 provided `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` approach listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/239219).

If user add new line to `UITextView`, and so textView, cell height should increase, how can I update height?

Tried:

```
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
```

These does not work.

If I reload cell, like

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([iindexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
```

this works, but then I need to deal with resign and show keyboard. I would avoid it. Any workaround?

Answer (score 8):

need to add following method:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

it will update constraints without reloading tableview

Comment: This answer works without table view reload.  Tested in iOS9.

Comment: This works, as well, when changing the height constraint of a **view**, instead of a textView. Tested in *iOS10*.

Answer (score 0):

After sometime `textView` will start scrolling to make increase it height on new line ever time you need to implement `textViewDidChangeText:` method and increase its height by calculating height for text.

To use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` you need to add constraints to `subviews` from top to bottom, I think you should also create and IBOutlet for height constraint of textView and set constant value on `textViewDidChangeText` method, in that case `tableViewCell` height will change dynamically.

Comment: If I set height constraint, it will stop UITableViewAutomaticDimension to work

Comment: then increase its height by setting the frame